# How to lock a row so that a select returns a row exactly once?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, t-sql, sql-server-2014

SQL amateur here.

I have a table containing voucher codes:

```
id  voucherCode  UserId
------------------------
1   abcde        13
2   bcdef        11
3   cdefg
4   defgh
```

Now if one of my users qualify for a voucher code, I get one from my table:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM tableName WHERE UserId IS NULL;
UPDATE tableName SET UserId = @UserID WHERE id = @SelectedIdFromAboveSelect;
```

I have to be sure that each row is only selected **once**. If multiple users need a voucher code, there is a small time gap between the `SELECT` and the `UPDATE`. If then a second `SELECT` is executed, it may `SELECT` the same row a second time. How do I prevent that?

Comment: `TOP 1 ... FROM tableName` so you choose user based on execution plan.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you can do it in opposite order; I mean, you `UPDATE` the table with the user ID and then `SELECT` the voucherCode. This way you shouldn't have any problem.

Comment: To me, this answer qualifies as lateral thinking--love it! Work in controls to pick out which vouchercode was picked (based on max(id), probably) and some double-checking in case there were no vouchers to assign, and you're good.

Comment: And just how does this work?  If the user is in the table more than once how do you know which voucherCode was  just assigned?

Comment: I solved at in the meantime and some more googleing. That's exactly it, first update, but with subquery: UPDATE tableName SET UserId = @@UserId WHERE id = (SELECT TOP (1) id FROM tableName WHERE UserId IS NULL ORDER BY id ASC). After that I can do a SELECT * FROM tableName WHERE UserId = @@UserId

Comment: @Frisbee A user simply may not be more than once in the table. I will check that he is not yet in the table before expiring another voucher.

Comment: @Ollie And then you are back to what if the userID was added between the select and update

Comment: @Frisbee The UserId is the Id of the user my scripts runs for. There can not be a second script running at the same time with the same UserId.

Answer (score 3):

You can do this by returning the value in the `update` statement, using the `output` clause:

```
declare @ids table (userid int);

with toupdate as (
      SELECT TOP 1 *
      FROM tableName
      WHERE UserId IS NULL
     )
UPDATE toupdate
    SET UserId = @UserId
    OUTPUT inserted.UserId INTO @ids;
```

Comment: Thanks, seems like an elegant way to do this.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
UPDATE t
SET userid = 99
OUTPUT inserted.id, inserted.vouchercode
FROM tablename t
WHERE userid IS NULL
AND id = (SELECT MIN(id) 
          FROM tablename 
          WHERE userid IS NULL)
```

the OUTPUT is only for getting the id and code you actually selected.

Answer (score -2):

I think this may help :

SELECT DISTINCT * FROM tableName WHERE UserId IS NULL